# Want to load External JavaScript after complete page load : like Lazy Loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have external javascript which load exteral ads on my website

But because of that my speed of website goes slow and also google page speed score goes to bellow 50. The script is bellow

My site is in simple php and jquery bootstrap. I do not use wordpress

But i saw many wordpress sites which load javascript or images after complete page load

How i can do it simple php and jqyery site?

I want to load that script after complete page load

Also after research i came to see this http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/ but i am not able to understand how i can use this jquery plugin to solve my issue

Please anyone help me

Regards
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
window.onload = function(){
  <script language="JavaScript" src="<path and filename.js>"></script>
};
```

`<path and filename.js>` is the path/URL and filename of the .js file you want to load or insert.

Comment: where to put this code? in bottom of page or top. also i should include script src file again in code too?

Comment: Put it in `<script> </script>` tag of your main **js block**.

Comment: @gaurav, you must Vote for the solution that has worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can append a script like this:

```
$(function() {
   var script= $('script');
   script.attr('src', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js');
   $('body').append(script);
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z8rjym54/

To delay 2 seconds:

```
$(function() {
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() { 
        var script= $('script');
        script.attr('src', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js');
        console.log('appending...');
        $('body').append(script); 
    }, 2000);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sodbk3p6/

Comment: this code will load the js file after complete page load ? Can we add delay in this LIke i want to load my external js after 4 seconds of page load

Comment: also if i put my js file in this functon then i should include js file aggain in code or not and where to put this code? in bottom or top

Comment: i found a code here https://www.pixelnatures.in/2020/08/how-to-fast-loading-blogger-website.html but is it legle to use adsense

Comment: Svela, Your code will work but does not meet the requirement as @gaurav wants the .js file to be loaded after his main page is loaded.

Comment: basicly i want adsense to load after complete page load as it adsense reduce speed till 50%. i also want to know that its fine if i use script to load adense js file after page load

Comment: @gaurav, can you share the Path/URL of the .js file.

Comment: bascly i want that my all src tags like JS files, Image all load after 2 seconds on page. I do not want to add my js file path inside a js code

Comment: Means what i want. when anyone open my websit then after page load after 2 seconds my images and javascipt external file should load. but i do not wana put any external js file inside any js code. can u help me plese

Comment: Hello @Svela . you do not understand me. i want to delay all external js files even if i have 3 external js file. all load after 2 seconds of page load and i also do not want to put any js file like this         script.attr('src', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js');
 inside code. I do not want any js file inside any script. I want a code which load any js or image after 2 seconds without custmizing any js src include code